# Contar parâmetros GET - PHP

Tags: php

Como conto quantos parâmetros $_GET estão preenchidos? Fiz um count() no $_GET mas ele conta também a quantidade de valores vazios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer uma simples função para chegar os valores vazios:

```
<?php

function count_sem_vazios($array) {
    $contagem = 0;
    foreach ($array as $foo) {
        if (!empty($foo))
            $contagem++;
    }
    return $contagem;
}

// Demonstração:
$teste = array(
    null, // essa NÃO conta
    0, // essa NÃO conta
    'string', // essa conta (1)
    10, // essa conta (2)
    true, // essa conta (3)
    '' // essa NÃO conta
);

$contagem = count_sem_vazios($teste); // Retorna: 3

print_r($contagem);

// Para a variável $_GET:
// $contagem = count_sem_vazios($_GET);
```

---

Lembrando que o [empty()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) tem algumas considerações para **vazio**:

- `""` (uma string vazia)
- `0` (0 como um inteiro)
- `0.0` (0 como um ponto flutuante)
- `"0"` (0 como uma string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (um array vazio)
- `$var;` (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

Comment: Obrigado LipESprY, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre o empty()

Comment: Na realidade, não precisa focar muito no empty. Dei enfase apenas aos casos que ele considera vazio. Você deve utilizar uma fórmula de cordo com o conteúdo que você quer filtrar. Pode até criar um callback e utilizar em conjunto com a proposta do colega @rcs que vai dar muito certo! Cada caso é um caso. ;)

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizar a função `array_filter` para remover os valores vazios e depois contar o resultado retornado.

```
$valoresVaziosGet  = array_filter($_GET);
$contagemVaziosGet = count($valoresVaziosGet);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda rcs